# How to add a spline to rjags model

Tags: r, bayesian, jags, splines

I am having difficulty finding information in fitting splines using rjags (my motivation is to try to recreate a glm in jags to impute missing dependent values). Anyhow I can find very little info on this finding only this answer on Cross-validated: https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/79973/how-to-analyze-this-data-using-rjags-or-any-other-way/80650#80650. However, I cannot understand the splines code there (and do not have the reputation there to ask a question!). For one thing I don't understand why that code loops over both S & G.

Therefore, I have made a toy linear model in jags:

```
library(datasets)
library(rjags)
library(ggplot2)


# Specify a JAGS linear model

mk_jags_lin_mod <- function(prior.a, prior.b){
    sink(paste("lin_reg_jags.mod.txt", sep=""))
    cat(paste0("
               model {
               for (i in 1:N){
               y[i] ~ dnorm(y.hat[i], tau)
               y.hat[i] <- a + b * x[i]
               }
               a ~ ",prior.a,
               "\tb ~ ",prior.b,
               "\ttau <- pow(sigma, -2)
               sigma ~ dunif(0, 100)
               }
               "))
    sink()
}

# Define a default vague prior
default <- "dnorm(0, .0001)\n"

mk_jags_lin_mod(default, default)

# Initialise
jags.cars <- jags.model('lin_reg_jags.mod.txt',
                              data = list('x' = mtcars$hp,
                                          'y' = mtcars$mpg,
                                          'N' = nrow(mtcars)),
                              n.chains = 2,
                              n.adapt = 1000)

# Burn-in
update(jags.cars, 5000) 

# Sample
coda.cars <- coda.samples(jags.cars, variable.names = c('a', 'b', 'y.hat','tau'), n.iter = 1000)

# Extract posterior estimates
coda.sum <- summary(coda.cars)
q <- coda.sum$quantiles

mtcars$fit <- q[4:35 , 3]

ggplot(data=mtcars, aes(x=hp, y=mpg)) + geom_point() +
    geom_line(aes(y=fit, col="red"))
```

My question is: how to I add a restricted cubic spline to the 'b' estimate in the linear model ?

Comment: Check jagam: https://stat.ethz.ch/R-manual/R-devel/library/mgcv/html/jagam.html

Comment: Hi, thanks for the tip but looking at the examples in that command and the jags model it makes I still can't figure it out how to modify my model code above. I prefer to specify the model directly myself as I want to recreate a previous model - jagam seems to dynamically pick spline knots - thats won't work for me

Answer (score 0):

Ok so it took me most of the day but I finally figured it out... I think....
I modified the model as follows:

```
 model {
   for (i in 1:N){
     y[i] ~ dnorm(y.hat[i], tau)
     y.hat[i] <- a + beta[1] + beta[2]*x[i] + beta[3]*pow(x[i], 2) + beta[4]*pow(x[i], 3)
   }

   a ~ dnorm(0, .0001)

   # Specify priors for spline terms
   for (k in 1:4) {
     beta.mu[k] ~ dnorm(0, 100)
     beta.tau[k] ~ dgamma(0.01, 10)
     beta[k] ~ dnorm(beta.mu[k], beta.tau[k])
   }
     tau <- pow(sigma, -2)
     sigma ~ dunif(0, 100)
   }
```

The value of k must be at least 4 but thereafter increasing k increases the smooth. Otherwise I think my math is correct (though I am open to corrections!).

Comment: The scale parameter of `dnorm` must be specified as precision, so maybe you mean `beta.mu[k] ~ dnorm(0, 100^-2)`. But do you really need to estimate hyperparameters for `beta[k]`? I would have thought that `for (k in 1:4) beta[k] ~ dnorm(0, 0.0001)` would suit your needs.

Comment: Hey yes you are probably correct - I'm not very good and am reverse engineering other bits of code really so this was just an oversite. But thank you @jbaums for making my model simpler!! :)

Comment: @jbaums - Is there any way to 'loosen' the fit of the model ? In my real data when I predict missing values they are basically dead on the fit line - I'd like to see more spread in the predictions.

Comment: When you're looking at simulated missing data, are you monitoring `y`, or `y.hat`?

Comment: y (just to be sure I plotted both - definitely y has a little more spread but it is still very quite tight). I have a lot of data points - 2600 or so - could it simply be data driven ? I've changed tau to `tau ~ dgamma(0.001,0.001)` and it had no effect that I could see

Comment: The observations are distributed around the expected values, as Normal(y.hat, sigma^2). That standard deviation is estimated from the data. If you have missing data, they will be simulated by first calculating the expected value (i.e. `a + beta[1] + beta[2]*x[i] + beta[3]*pow(x[i], 2) + beta[4]*pow(x[i], 3)`), and then adding Normal error with the estimated standard deviation.

Comment: Yes that is my understanding. So if I really wanted slightly more random predictions I could add in a something like y2 ~ y * dnorm(1, 0.001) and monitor that in the coda output ? I assume this would not effect the original estimates for y and the model in general ? (Although I'll have to think about whether its valid to do this or not). EDIT - on second thoughts - better/faster to do this in R ?

Comment: It really depends whether you have any reason to expect the missing data to be more dispersed than the observed data. It might be worth taking a look at [Gelman and Hill's missing data imputation chapter](http://www.stat.columbia.edu/~gelman/arm/missing.pdf). [This paper](http://www.stat.columbia.edu/~gelman/research/published/mipaper.pdf) might also be useful.

Comment: @jbaums The following occurs: The post. predict. I am plotting is the mean of 2 chains x 1000 samples. As such it is the most probable value for the dependent variable at the given values of the independent variables, with the spread of probable values described by the distribution of the coda estimates. Of course it fits tightly as an average of 2000 post. preds. Therefore - instead of reintroducing a random element - I should just use the post. pred. from one coda sample. It seems interpreting the mean of estimates is a frequentist interpretation of Bayesian model. No?

Comment: Sure, you can take a single sample, from a single chain, if you just want random data consistent with your model. The Bayesian maximum a posteriori estimate of a parameter with an uninformative prior is equivalent to the frequentist maximum likelihood estimate. (Note that the posterior mean is not always the most probable value for your random variable)